# After sudo passwd -e [user] , then I login getting an “Authentication token manipulation” error

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, permissions, login, password

I try to expire a password of a user, called student, within a root circumstance.However, When I run 'sudo passwd -e student' and login student, there is a error as below:

```
Junzuo:Linux Echo$ ssh student@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
student@127.0.0.1's password:
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
Last login: Fri Jan 13 09:22:09 2017 from 10.0.2.2
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for student.
(current) UNIX password:
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

P.S I can change the user student's password within root environment.So the /etc/shadow file is read/write in my opinion.Furthermore, I try the way of

```
mount -o remount,rw /
chmod 640 /etc/shadow
```

But it doesn't work.Could anybody give me an advice to solve it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: My purpose is to expire a user's password within root but not change its password immediately. The user can change the password next time he login.@RajeshKeladimath

Comment: By the way, I have seen the link before asking the question and I think the /etc/shadow has mounted as read/write.@RajeshKeladimath

Comment: I can change the user student's password directly within root circumstance.@RajeshKeladimath

Comment: If you have already added ssh public key to authorized keys list, then you can execute only execute first command "sudo passwd -d student" and then try to login using ssh.

Comment: Try these steps : ssh-keygen -t rsa ,
ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub student@localhost -p 2222 ,
sudo passwd student -d ,
ssh student@localhost -p 2222

Comment: I have just learned ssh authorized_keys to login server.Okay, I think that's a better way and I will choose that. But it's a password login problem and I still want to know the error reason.

Answer (score 1):

A way to fix this issue is to remount filesystem and then to check permissions of /etc/shadow file.

```
$ mount -rw -o remount /
# or
$ mount -o remount,rw /
```

Check the write permission of /etc/shadow file.

```
$ ls -l /etc/shadow
-rw-r----- 1 root shadow 1025 Feb  11 22:11 /etc/shadow
```

That's OK, now passwd will work well.

```
$ sudo passwd USERNAME
```

Comment: That's right but it's not my purpose.You can have a glance at the above comments.